# Bash script error: ./step-2.sh: line 9: ((: i=: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "=")

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

## This script extracts snapshot times from EDS such that RMSD between chosen consecutive frames lie within a narrow range: say 0.45-0.60 Å. Play with these limits in order to find optimal values


rm snap-time-mtd.txt
low_limit=0.45
up_limit=0.60 

for ((i=1; i<=501; i=$j))
do
# check RMSD to target; if it is smaller than lower limit then we are done
echo 3 3 | gmx rms -f pdb/$(($i-1)).pdb -s active-"6".pdb -o test.xvg
rm '#'*
rmsd=$(tail -1 test.xvg | awk '{print $2*10}')
check=$(echo "$rmsd > $low_limit" | bc)
if [ $check == 1 ] 
then
j=$(awk -v low="$low_limit" -v up="$up_limit" -v frame="$i" 'BEGIN {RS=""; FS="\n"} NR==frame {for(k=frame;k<=NF;k++){ if($k>=low && $k<=up){print k; break} } } END{}' rmsd-matrix/matrix.txt)
echo $rmsd
echo $(($i-1)) >> snap-times.txt
else
break
fi
done
```

and i keep getting this error:

```
./step-2.sh: line 10: ((: i=: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "=")
```

Comment: ... probably because `j` is uninitialized

Comment: .... and possibly an infinite loop will occur here if `j <= 501` .

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: You must have some extra lines before the code you've given us - the assignment is on line 5 here, not line 9

Comment: Sorry, now the script is exactly the same that I used when I got this error msg. I tried using shellcheck, but even with no warning the script didn't write anything to the txt file at the end

Comment: Run your script with `bash -x` to see what's going on.

Comment: Remove the `$` symbols in front of variable names inside `((`...`))` expressions - including the `for` loop declaration

Comment: How do you run the script?